# Display ACF data as post title on 'publish' of Wordpress post?

Tags: php, wordpress, advanced-custom-fields

Here is my code:

```
function my_post_title_updater( $post_id ) {

$my_post = array();
$my_post['ID'] = $post_id;

$brand = get_field('brand');
$asset = get_field('asset');
$language = get_field('language');

$countryfield = get_field_object('country');
$countryvalue = get_field('country');
$country = $countryfield['choices'][ $countryvalue ];

if ( get_post_type() == 'project' ) {
  $my_post['post_title'] = $brand . ' ' . $asset . ' ' . $country . ' ' . $language ;
}

wp_update_post( $my_post );

}

add_action('acf/save_post', 'my_post_title_updater', 20);
```

On publishing a Wordpress post this function is supposed to create a title based on a few Advanced Custom Fields. At the moment what it does is gets 'brand', 'asset' and 'language', but not 'country'. However, upon clicking 'update' of the post it will then display the country in the title.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: what it is supposed to do ?

Comment: I'm fairly sure I explained in my post, didn't I? Which part is unclear?

Comment: Have you checked if this is throeing a failure when activating WP_DEBUG?

Comment: Cheers for your reply! WP_DEBUG was set to true and, as far as I can remember, it wasn't throwing a failure. However, it was under a tight deadline so i had to find a workaround instead.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
$country = $countryfield['choices'] . $countryvalue;
```

Comment: Unfortunately that doesn't display anything on publish either. Cheers for your help, though!